# What is the difference between Apple MB110LB/B and Apple MB110Z/B keyboards

Tags: keyboard

I am looking for a QWERTY US layout apple keyboard, on amazon I found several models and this made me confused.

My current keyboard looks like this, I thinks this is the standard US QWERY layout, isn't it? Anyways, I am looking for this model. Is it MB110Z/B?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One seems to be the “USA” keyboard, the other one is the “International English” keyboard, you can see pictures of them (click to zoom in) on the Apple Store sites:

**MB110LB/B**: http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB110LB/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad

**MB110Z/B**: http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB110Z/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-international-english

Both have a basic QWERTY layout, but have some differences in the other keys. The layout around the ‘return’ key and of the key itself differs a little. The left shift key is shorter on the International English keyboard, and it has an extra key for ‘§’ and ‘±’ (below the ‘esc’ key) which doesn't appear at all on the USA keyboard. Finally, the USA keyboard uses words on some keys like ‘tab’ and ‘shift’ where the International English one use images.

I'm not sure if there's any difference between the “MB110LB/B” and “MB110LL/B” keyboards, the latter one is more clearly labeled “USA”:

**MB110LL/B**: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa

Based on the Logitech keyboard of which you showed a picture, I assume you want the “USA” one.

Comment: Ohh excellent! Well at work I used an International English keyboard and at home I use the exact same board I posted ( USA layout ). I will pick the International English one I guess. But now I know what the difference is.

Comment: The physical location of the "extra key" is of course next to the z and not below the esc key.  With the US layout active, this extra international key is used for `/~, which is below esc on the American keyboard.  The key below esc is then used for §/±, which is at option 6 and option shift = on the American keyboard.